# Fixed table header with horizontal AND vertical scrolling body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Objectives**:

- Column width of table header and table body should be same.
- Table header to be fixed on vertical scroll.
- Table header to be moved on horizontal scroll.
- Header to be displayed inside scroll-able division of HTML.

**Problem statements:**

- Table header does not get fixed on vertical scroll.
- Header displayed out of scroll-able division of HTML(When header position is fixed).

I have seen many posts, but could not find the solution to this particular problem statement.

I have created two JSFiddles to demonstrate the problem statements:

Fiddle01: Solution works good as a separate module.
[JSFiddle01](https://jsfiddle.net/vishruthjain/Lxz98htp/28/)

Fiddle02: Solution does not work when its integrated with other divs.
[JSFiddle02](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxz98htp/60/)

Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
$(function() {
var $window = $(window);
var $table = $('table');
var $head = $table.find('thead');
var $body = $table.find('tbody');
var $headTds1 = $head.find('tr').eq(0).find('th');
var $headTds2 = $head.find('tr').eq(1).find('th');
var $bodyTds = $body.find('tr').eq(0).find('td');
var tableWidth = $table.outerWidth();
// console.log("Width:"+tableWidth);
var $tableNew = $('<table/>');
var cl = 0; // colspan total length
var cc = 0; // colspan count

$table.css({ width: tableWidth });
$tableNew
    .attr("class", $table.attr("class"))
    .css({ width: tableWidth });

$head.css({ background: '#fff' });

$.each($headTds1, function(index, value) {
    var $headTd = $(value);
    var colspan = $headTd.attr('colspan') || 0;

    if (colspan) {
        while (colspan) {
            addwidth($($headTds2[cl]), $($bodyTds[index + cl - cc]));
            colspan--
            cl++
        }
        cc++;
    } else {
        addwidth($headTd, $($bodyTds[index + cl - cc]));
    }
});

function addwidth($headTd, $bodyTd) {
    var headTdwidth2 = $headTd.outerWidth();
    var bodyTdwidth2 = $bodyTd.outerWidth();
    var width2 = headTdwidth2 > bodyTdwidth2 ? headTdwidth2 : bodyTdwidth2;

    $bodyTd.css({ 'width': width2 });
    $headTd.css({ 'width': width2 });

    var headTdwidth = $headTd.width();
    var bodyTdwidth = $bodyTd.width();
    var width = headTdwidth > bodyTdwidth ? headTdwidth : bodyTdwidth;
    $bodyTd.html('<div style="width: ' + width + 'px">' + $bodyTd.html() + '</div>');
    $headTd.html('<div style="width: ' + width + 'px">' + $headTd.html() + '</div>');
}

$head.appendTo($tableNew);
$tableNew.insertBefore($table);
// $table.css({ 'margin-top': $tableNew.height() });

$tableNew.css({ position: 'fixed' });

$window.scroll(reLeft);
$window.resize(reLeft);


function reLeft() {
    $tableNew.css({ left: $table.offset().left - $window.scrollLeft() });
}
});
```

Comment: try this library tableHeadFixer.js $("table").tableHeadFixer({ "head": true, "left": 4,"foot":true });

Comment: @ShahidAwan, Have tried the library, it freezes columns, and does not freeze header, https://github.com/lai32290/TableHeadFixer, please refer my fiddles.

Comment: Someone please respond to my question with solutions.

Comment: @WEshruth I see your `Fiddle01` works. Why didn't you use it?

Comment: @Duannx Yes it works as separate , but it does not work when I integrate it, it won’t, https://jsfiddle.net/Lxz98htp/60/

Comment: What is wrong with fiddle01?

Comment: @SalmanA Fiddle01 works perfectly fine, it fails when same function applied with other divs, which is fiddle02, my objective is to make it integrated in my application. Which is the hurdle now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are cloning the table for fix header, better you can direct fix the header of original table which will results the same.

Element with `position:fixed` changes the width with respect to viewport, which results width gets change on scrolling as you can check here https://jsfiddle.net/chourasiapawankumar/vg7q3tyc/19

**Approach:1**

> **instead of `position:fixed` use `relative` in `th`** and it is working with your parent `div` which has `min-height:100px`.
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/chourasiapawankumar/krw0qpbL/62/

**Approach:2**

> You can see both horizontal and vertical scroll bar at a time on removing `min-height` of parent div which I have commented in the below fiddle.
>
> https://jsfiddle.net/chourasiapawankumar/vg7q3tyc/33/

Comment: It does not keep the width of table header and body on scroll @Pawan, have tried below code with your solution.
     `var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
     if (scroll >= 60) {
     header.addClass("fixed");
      ("#table1.fixed").css("left", "60px");
      reLeft();
      } else {
      header.removeClass("fixed");
      }`
Did not solve.

Comment: yea, it is because of `position:fixed`, which changes the `width` with respect to viewport. try adding css `width:$table.width()` in reLeft(), but it will not help I guess in this case.

Comment: Have seen your new fiddle, thank you for that, below line of code is essential for my application, can not remove it,
`<div tableheight="100 " class=" brickChart whiteB analyticDiv o-auto" id="an8080419b-029d-41d2-88ba-4d79019b1e933203836Div" style="overflow-x: scroll; min-height: 100px; margin-top: 3%; cursor: wait;">` even though my header width would vary on scroll.

Comment: I wonder, on vertical scroll, why the width of columns get change (Mismatch between body and header) after 5 column (column name: df) 
That will cause lot of alignment problems till end of n'th column.

Comment: header width is not changing now, can you check 2nd and 3rd fiddle. Already answer why width is getting changed

Answer (score 3):

Dunno if you can/want to use a library, but [floatHead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/) works nicely and it looks like it does what you want... Go on the linked page and click the Demo "Run FloatHead" button, you will see it in action.

Answer (score 3):

The most common trick for scrollable tables is to create a clone of the table and display the `<thead>` from first clone and `<tbody>` from the second. This is done to ensure that both sections have identical structure and column widths. The following uses this idea + sticky positioning:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".fixed_headers").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='scrollable-table'></div>");
    $(this).clone().insertBefore(this);
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css);

.scrollable-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.scrollable-table table:nth-child(1) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.scrollable-table table:nth-child(1) tbody {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.scrollable-table table:nth-child(2) thead {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p style="text-align: center;">Best viewed in full page</p>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover fixed_headers">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">Store_Country</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">Brand</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">Product Description</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">12</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">df</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">trr</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">Tax onlatest periodofthe fiscal17</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">df1</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">121</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre41</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre42</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre43</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre431</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre433</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre434</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre435</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre436</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre437</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre438</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre439</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4310</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4311</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4312</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4313</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4314</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4315</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4316</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre4317</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">4455tre43171</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">Tax on latest period of the fiscal15</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">Tax on latest period of the fiscal16</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">Taxon latest period ofthefiscal18</th>
        <th class="nb_custom_th">Taxon latest period ofthefiscal181</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="nb_custom_tr">
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">India</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">Apple</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">Apple iPad 4 16GB Wi-Fi + Cellular</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">3520</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">3520</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">3520</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">3520</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">3520</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">3520</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6620</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nb_custom_tr">
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">India</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">Apple</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">Apple iPad Air</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">1895</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">1895</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">1895</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">1895</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">1895</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">1895</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">79875</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nb_custom_tr">
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">India</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">Apple</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">Apple iPad Mini</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2602</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2602</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2602</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2602</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2602</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2602</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">6245</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="nb_custom_tr">
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">India</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">Apple</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td drillHandler">Apple IPhone 4S 64GB</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2963</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2963</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2963</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2963</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2963</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2963</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
        <td class="nb_custom_td" style="text-align: right;">2827</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we use this function with cloning only header,not cloning the entire table and keeping header and body width same? `$(this).clone().insertBefore(this);` as tables of our web application has huge number of rows and columns, cloning of entire slowing down the performance.

Comment: @WEshruth if you follow that approach then you'll have to calculate the widths of header cells, then clone the header and apply those widths on clone (just as you were doing in your original example). `colspan` will make the code complicated though.

Comment: Can’t we clone only one row of the table, which will keep our width same, it helps performance.

Comment: Yes you can if that row is enough to determine the widths of all rows.

Comment: Ok, thank you, if possible can you please post the code to clone the header and one row of the table body.

Comment: How can I set the width of the individual columns? <th style="width:150px"> 1234</th> doesn't do the trick for me.

Comment: How can I dynamically set the max-height from javascript?