# Extra horizontal scroll bar on fixed-header HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I've got some HTML tables with a lot of columns. I'm currently trying to upgrade these tables to have fixed headers, so I went through examples online that say to make table-layout fixed, thead and tbody blocks, constrain the height for tbody, and set overflow-y on tbody. That all works fine, my data scrolls while the headers stay put.

However, whenever I have enough columns that the width overflows the viewport, I'm getting two horizontal scrollbars that I didn't ask for. I'm not setting overflow or overflow-x anywhere, yet I'm getting two horizontal scrollbars - one for tbody only, and one for the whole table. Scrolling with the tbody one shows all the data but leaves the headers in place so they don't line up with the data, and scrolling the table one doesn't allow you to see data past the original viewport because there's a vertical scroll bar where the right edge of the viewport originally was.

I'm actually using an old version of Vuetify (no, I can't upgrade), but I've narrowed things down a lot and reproduced the problem with a simple HTML/CSS-only example [here](https://codepen.io/sgarfio/pen/eYZjGrz). Can anybody explain to me where the horizontal scrollbars are coming from? I do want one horizontal scrollbar, probably the one for the table, but I want it to scroll both the data and the headers. Presumably getting rid of the tbody scrollbar will do that, but I'm not defining it anywhere, so I don't know how to remove it. In fact the inspector doesn't show overflow-x anywhere at all! I've tried adding overflow-x to various elements to try to force a scrollbar so that these automatic ones don't need to show up, but no luck so far.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Sample CSS:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

thead tr, tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

th, td {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<html>
  <div style="max-width: 500px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td>
          <td>Data2</td>
          <td>Data3</td>
          <td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td>
          <td>Data6</td>
          <td>Data7</td>
          <td>Data8</td>
        <tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td>
          <td>Data2</td>
          <td>Data3</td>
          <td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td>
          <td>Data6</td>
          <td>Data7</td>
          <td>Data8</td>
        <tr>
        <!-- more rows to make it scroll vertically -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7t2qbLgn/ here's a jsfiddle for people. I'm currently on a mobile browser, and I do not see double horizontal scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar you are talking about is being added to the `tbody` element. By turning `tbody` into a block, `overscroll:auto` is being added by default, even though you only include `overflow-y` in your CSS:

```
thead tr, tbody {
  display: block;
}
tbody {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

**Partial Solution (*works when there is no horizontal overflow*)**

Adding `overflow-y:hidden` to `tbody` will remove the second horizontal scrollbar, and this works when there is no horizontal overflow. However if there is, the vertical scrollbar gets "stuck" to the column positioned at the max-width and scrolls with the tbody, as you can see here:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

thead tr, tbody {
  display: block;
}

tbody {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

th, td {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div style="max-width: 500px; overflow-y: auto;">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

The big issue is that making the `tbody` scroll independently of the `thead` vertically (which we want because we want to keep the headings) also stops it working on a *horizontal* scroll (which we don't because the headings don't move with the tbody).

**CSS-only solution for horizontal & vertical overflow (*partial browser support*)**

Using `position:sticky` for the header row will keep it positioned at the top of the table as the rest of the table scrolls up behind it:

```
th {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   background: #FFF; /* otherwise we can see the scrolling data behind it */
}
table {
  /* prevent the th scrolling up by the default border size before "sticking" */
  border-collapse: collapse;  
}
```

However this only has [partial browser support](https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky). Note that it only works on `th` (and not`thead` or `tr`) in Chrome, FF and others.

**Working Example** (or not, depending on your browser!):

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /* the prevents the th scrolling up by the default border size before "sticking" */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <p>This is some content to show the effect of the sticky header and top:0 on the rest of the page </p>
  <div style="max-width: 500px; height:200px; overflow: auto;">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p>This is some content to show the effect of the sticky header and top:0 on the rest of the page </p>
</html>
```

**Javascript/jQuery Solution**

This is tagged as CSS & HTML, but I'll just mention this here as JS is the only sure way to do this with the widest browser support.

- Codepen from "Springborg" with 2 options: https://codepen.io/springborg/pen/MvPmPP
- This SO question has various of ways to clone the table to create the header row separately: [Fixed table header with horizontal AND vertical scrolling body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792395/fixed-table-header-with-horizontal-and-vertical-scrolling-body)

[Salman A's answer from that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792395/#53886635) creates a clone of the table, and displays the `<thead>` from first and `<tbody>` from the second. This is easily implemented in your example - see below:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".fixed_headers").each(function() {
    $(this).wrap("<div class='scrollable-table'></div>");
    $(this).clone().insertBefore(this);
  });
});
```

```css
.scrollable-table {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.scrollable-table table:nth-child(1) {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.scrollable-table table:nth-child(1) tbody {
  visibility: collapse;
}

.scrollable-table table:nth-child(2) thead {
  visibility: collapse;
}

th, td {
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <div style="max-width: 500px;">
    <table class="fixed_headers">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Column 1</th>
          <th>Column 2</th>
          <th>Column 3</th>
          <th>Column 4</th>
          <th>Column 5</th>
          <th>Column 6</th>
          <th>Column 7</th>
          <th>Column 8</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data1</td><td>Data2</td><td>Data3</td><td>Data4</td>
          <td>Data5</td><td>Data6</td><td>Data7</td><td>Data8</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! I'm working on adapting a version of Salman A's solution that you linked. I'm not using JQuery and I have to deal with all the markup that Vuetify generates, but I think I can do something similar using two v-data-tables. I got it mostly working and then my power went out lol. I'll update again once I get it working and maybe update my CodePen with a minimal solution.

Comment: @SherylGarfio Glad to help! Each question on SO should be about one specific problem - in this case it was why you you have 2 scrollbars and was tagged for HTML and CSS. I mentioned JS as an option because its the best way to do it, but changing the focus of the question is discouraged here on SO so I suggest you don't change it to include your JS :) If you do have further questions about the JS, you are welcome to post another question about that, you can even reference this one if it helps. But I think this answer solves the current question that was asked :)

Comment: Good point. I was using my CodePen to try things out in an isolated manner, but I've reverted everything now so that it shows the original problem.

What I ended up doing was making the outer div's overflow "hidden", which gets rid of the outer scroll bar leaving the one on tbody. Then I added a scroll event handler to tbody, which scrolls thead by the same amount using the scrollLeft property. I also had to make thead's overflow "hidden" so that it would react to having its scrollLeft property manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
table {
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden; // New Entry
    }
```

By Default overflow value is visible for both x and y But t-body you again use overflow-y: auto; due to which it happens and two of scroll are displayed.

Comment: That does get rid of the table scrollbar, but that's the one I want to keep :). This suggestion makes it so that the tbody scrolls horizontally, but not the thead, so when you are scrolling the data does not line up with its headers. This might be a clue though, so thanks for the explanation about the defaults. That must be why the inspector does not show it, because it's not coming from any CSS file. I'll keep poking at it in the morning!